# Way to make Parse push notifications periodic

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

Is there a way to make the Parse push notifications be received only during a specific period? For example, the user may have a preference of not receiving any notification during the night. Is it possible (or does the Parse API provide a way) to make the subscription to a particular channel valid only during a preset period on a per user basis, without making any changes in the server that sends the notification to Parse?

Comment: I think it is not possible , but we can schedule the  notification for specific time to send

Answer (score 0):

You can define as some of the **Background** jobs in parse...

Here is the [Official Documentation](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-background-jobs/)

Introducing the new **Channels** with these **customized Background jobs** can make you achieve for what your trying.

Or refer here [Stackoverflow's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811696/parse-ios-send-push-notification-at-specific-time)

Comment: The question is not about scheduled notifications, rather about creating a silent period within which no notifications are received by the client.